# Why is this simple mask shader failing?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to create a "transition" effect between two 2D scenes.  I have 3 textures: `before`, `after`, and `mask`.  `before` and `after` are self-explanatory.  `mask` is a simple monochrome texture that defines how the first two get composited.  It changes over time, to perform the transition.  All 3 textures are the same size.

I've verified that all 3 textures contain the correct data, but when I try to perform the compositing, I end up with either `before` in its entirety, or `after` in its entirety, seemingly at random.

Here's what I'm doing:

Application code:

```
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE1_ARB);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);
after.handle.bind;
glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE2_ARB);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);
mask.handle.bind;
glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB);
before.handle.bind;
GShaders.UseShaderProgram(maskProgramHandle); //GShaders: Global shader engine
GShaders.SetUniformValue(maskProgramHandle, 'before', 0);
GShaders.SetUniformValue(maskProgramHandle, 'after', 1);
GShaders.SetUniformValue(maskProgramHandle, 'mask', 2);
before.DrawFull; //draws the texture to the screen as a quad.
glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
```

Vertex shader:

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 texture_coordinate; 

void main() 
{ 
  gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex; 
  texture_coordinate = vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0); 
  v_color = gl_Color;
  gl_FrontColor = gl_Color; 
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2DRect before;
uniform sampler2DRect after;
uniform sampler2DRect mask;
varying vec2 texture_coordinate; 

void main()
{   
   vec3 maskValue = texture2DRect(mask, texture_coordinate).rgb;
   float alpha = (maskValue.r + maskValue.g + maskValue.b) / 3.0;
   vec4 beforeValue = texture2DRect(before, texture_coordinate);
   vec4 afterValue = texture2DRect(after, texture_coordinate);

   gl_FragColor = mix(beforeValue, afterValue, alpha);
}
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: By the way, you are using GLSL shaders, which in no way could ever be done on pre GL 1.3 hardware. So stop using a 15 year old extension for multitexturing.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Mind being a bit more specific?  The same basic model works fine on other multitexture code.  I don't have a huge level of in-depth OpenGL knowledge, especially about what's historically "good" and historically "bad" and what the latest fashions are, so any clarifications in this area would be welcome.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: can you provide more parts of the drawing and texture setup code? The shaders do look OK to me.

Comment: @MasonWheeler It's just that multitexturing is part of core OpenGL since virtually ever which is why you can omit all those `ARB`s on all the functions and constants. Whoever told you to use those names can confidentally be regarded as outdated and to be replaced by other learning resources.

Comment: @derhass: What else do you need? I think that's pretty much everything that's relevant...

Comment: @MasonWheeler What values are you passing for `texture_coordinate`?  `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB` uses non-normalized (i.e., not in the range [0,1]) texture coordinates.  With texture rectangle, folks often use `gl_FragCoord.xy` as their texture coordinates for this type of compositing operation.

Comment: @radical7: It's in the vertex shader: `texture_coordinate = vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0);`

Comment: @MasonWheeler *"It's in the vertex shader"* - Of course it is, but what values are you putting in as texture coordinates of the vertices? Rectangle textures just don't work like usual 2D textures regarding addressing.

Comment: @ChristianRau: `(0,0)`, `(0, height)`, `(width, height)`, and `(width, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is only guessing, have you tried this

```
gl_FragColor = mix(beforeValue, afterValue, alpha / 255.0f);
```